# What is the namespace for testng.xml?

Tags: testng

Instead of DTD I want to use xmlns.

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
```

Does any one know the namespace for testng.xml ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is only a DTD for the TestNG XML. No schema or namespace exists right now.